# Somar coluna do DataGrid apenas com valores válidos

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estou usando essa função para somar uma coluna do meu datagrid

```
public void Somatorio()
{
    decimal total = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_inico.Rows)
    {
        total += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["valor"].Value);
    }

    lbl_soma.Text = Convert.ToDouble(total).ToString("C");
}
```

A questão é que pode haver um campo da coluna sem valor, ai gera um erro, como eu faço para somar a coluna mas apenas os campos que contem o valor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifique seu `foreach` para considerar apenas as as linhas que contenham a coluna `valor` não vazias.

Estou usando `LINQ` e `C# 6`.

```
using System.Linq;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_inico.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
.Where(t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Cells["valor"].Value?.ToString())))
{
   total += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["valor"].Value);
}
```

Neste código estou usando checagem sequencial, ou seja, mesmo se o valor da coluna for nulo, não dá erro.

Comment: Funcionou, Muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Se o ponto for apenas não somar os que não contenham valor, tenta este código:

```
public void Somatorio()
{
    decimal total = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_inico.Rows)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(row.Cells["valor"].Value))
            total += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["valor"].Value);
    }

    lbl_soma.Text = Convert.ToDouble(total).ToString("C");
}
```

Assim só serão contabilizadas as colunas em que o valor não seja vazio.

Comment: É exatamente isso que preciso mas gerou um erro

Print do erro http://pt-br.tinypic.com/r/2gx1hzs/9

Comment: .Value é um objeto, e a função espera uma string, basta comparar se Value é null

Comment: `if (row.Cells["valor"].Value != null)` coloca esse if, antes do if atual

Comment: vou editar a resposta então.. pra ficar mais bonito :P `Convert.ToString()` é mais legal

Answer (score 1):

Use linq, isso vai resolver o seu problema:

```
using System.Linq;    

dgv_inico.AsEnumerable().Sum(c => c.Field<double>("valor"))
```